# Azure Functions Service Bus Output Binding - Non C# Languages

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

Is there any way to apply value of some filter when we use this type of output binding. I want message to be sent to only one subscription with specific correlation filter, and it looks like it is not supported. Right now i am doing that with SDK instead, but that actually makes my function's performance really slow. Does anyone have some insights if this is going to be supported, or some workaround different than using SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Below is something you can try to achieve your requirement.

- You can change the [output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-output?pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=in-process) of Azure functions to HTTP and then use logic apps to send the message with Correlation ID filter.

Below is the Logic app flow

[image]